# How to add correct import when using Structural replace on Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When adding elements to Java code using Intellij Structural find/replace, how can i add the missing imports?

For example, on doing the following Structural (not text, not regex) search:

find:

```
@$Annotation [Text=Autowired]$
$FieldType$ $Field [Text=X]$ = $Init$;
```

Replace:

```
@Lazy
@$Annotation$
$FieldType$ $Field$ = $Init$;
```

It correctly adds the annotation on the right place

```
@Autowired
@Getter
Private X x;
// Is replaced with:
@Getter
@Lazy
@Autowired
Private X x;
```

But, it won't add the import as there are more than one option for Lazy class. How can I instruct Intellij to also add `import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;` to the replaced file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fully qualified names in the replacement and enable the `Shorten fully qualified names` checkbox. This will add the imports when replacing.